# Unity вылетает когда нажимаю Run

Tags: c#, unity3d

Проблема в том, что я не могу запустить проект Unity, потому что, когда я нажимаю кнопку Run, я получаю краш и уведомление «Сообщить об ошибке».

По шагам, что я делаю: у меня есть PC(ORIG), на котором я установил Unity и создал проект, использующий мою `.dll`, и он отлично работает на моем PC. Также у меня на компьютере есть виртуальная машина Hyper-V (Win10). Эта виртуальная машина совершенно чистая, и там была установлена только Unity. Затем я копирую всю папку с проектом Unity со своего PC (ORIG) на виртуальную машину и открываю ее в Unity, после открытия нажимаю Run и получаю краш.

Я думал, что может быть проблема с отсутствием `.dll`, что мой PC(ORIG) использует какие то внутренее dll(и поэтому это работает), а на VM этого нет(и это причина краша). Чтою это проверить я открыл DependencyWalker на своей VM

[image]

Похоже, с `.dll`s проблем нет.

Просто для теста я также попытался скопировать этот проект на другой компьютер, на котором также установлена Unity, и там проект также работает без проблем.

Итак, вопрос в том, как узнать, в чем проблема с VM, потому что этот проект работает на моем PC и на другом PC и только на VM Unity - нет.

Есть ли возможность как то получить stack trace или описание ошибки? Потому, что как я сказал как только я нажимаю на Run, Unity сразу закрывается и только сообщение на экране

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Я не специалист в Unity, но нельзя ли для тестов отловить необработаное исключение (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.appdomain.unhandledexception) и вывести stacktrace не консоль или в файл?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unity сохраняет логи редактора в эти папки: ([документация](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/LogFiles.html))

| Operating system | Log files |
| --- | --- |
| Linux | ~/.config/unity3d/Editor.log |
| macOS | ~/Library/Logs/Unity/Editor.log |
| Window | C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Unity\Editor\Editor.log |

Обычно, содержащейся там информации достаточно для выявления проблемы.